# Saving non existent doctrine2 relations with zero instead of null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, legacy

In a legacy system we have a database that saves non existent relations with 0 instead of null. How can I get doctrine to save the parent row with 0 in the related column instead of null?

### Example:

**Comment-Table**

```
------------------------------------
| id | user_id | comment           |
------------------------------------
| 1    null      this is a comment |
| 2    1         another comment   |
------------------------------------
```

If I have an entity for that comment table I want it to save user_id = 0 in row 1 if there is no user for this comment. How can I achieve this?

Please consider, that I need this for a legacy system and changing the database schema so that null in that column is possible is no option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best bet it so manually insert 0 into user_id just before persisting in your controller.

```
$comment->setUserId(0);
$em->persist($comment);
```

Comment: Good answer, and I did try that. But I had no luck because if you double map that field with a real relation and a single field like your ID field doctrine still complains about that.

Comment: Great hint, never thought of that ;-)